# How to GET data by search word Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-rest-framework

I have problem getting the data to the home page.
I would like to filter out all the books based on Genre. I'm following the 
[MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Models) for this.

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Local Library Home</h1>

  <p>Welcome to <em>Local Library</em>, a very basic Django website.</p>

<h2>Dynamic content</h2>
<form action="" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="genre" placeholder="Search">
   <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^books/$', views.BookListView.as_view(), name='books'),
    url(r'^(?P<string>[-\w]+)$', views.GenreListView.as_view(), name='index'),
]
```

**GenreListView class**

```
class GenreListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    def get(request, string):
       try:
           book = Book.objects.all().filter(genre=string)
       except Book.DoesNotExist:
           raise Http404("Book does not exist")

     return render(
        request,
        'index.html',
        context={'book': book,}
    )
```

I can't figure out what I'm missing or what else I have to do to get all the date based on genre?

EDIT:
whole **index.html**

```
{%  extends "base_generic.html" %}

{%  block content %}
    <h1> Book List </h1>

    <form action="" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="genre" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

    {% if book_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for book in book_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ book.get_absolute_url }}">{{ book.title }}</a> ({{ book.author }})
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no books in the library</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: i don't get you, you mean you want the user to type a genere in a form then display the objects that matches that genere. tell me : )

Comment: yes. that exactly

Comment: i am using my phone now. but i will answer this question today please wait : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `get_queryset`, No need to rewrite `get`

```
class GenreListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        books = Book.objects.all()
        query = self.request.GET.get('genre', None)
        if query:
           return books.filter(genre=query)
        return books
```

> The exception ***`Book.DoesNotExist`*** will never
>   occur if you ***`filter()`*** queryset. it will always return a empty queryset in case of no object found

Comment: thanks!
I managed to get the request and value to the console, but I cant get values into the html file. what im still missing?

Comment: post your html where you are looping on list of books.

Comment: i have changed context variable name from `book_list` to `books` take care to change it in html also

Comment: remove `context_object_name ` from View, if you are using `book_list` in html, i have updated this n my answer have a look

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159330/discussion-between-satendra-and-averagejoe9000).